# Adding different amounts of time to dates

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I'm making a function in which I'm trying to store data in different date formats. I want to store the data in months or weeks depending on how many days there are. So basically, I mean to say that if I fetch data from two months, I want it to store the data in an array per week, like:

```
'1 2013' => 'some data',
'2 2013' => 'some data',
'3 2012' => 'some data',
```

And if I'm fetching data for more than three months, I want to store the data per month, so:

```
'Jan 2013' => 'some data',
'Feb 2013' => 'some data',
'Mar 2012' => 'some data',
```

Wanted to take into account that I might want to add more scenarios, so I made a conditional to determine the way the data is stored depending on the amount of days. It works with months, but for some reason it doesn't work with weeks. I keep adding a week to the date in a loop to get the next date. When I check the type of the $time variable after I call strtotime(), it says it's a boolean type. Don't understand why!

This is the relevant part of my code (edited bits out for clarity):

```
$times = array();
$length = 90;                   //Fetched data for 90 days.
$periods= round($length/7);     //Want to divide it up into weeks.
$per = 'week';
$format= 'W Y';

for($n = 0; $n < $periods; $n++){
    $time               = date($format, $start);

       //Here's apparently where it goes wrong:

    $time               = date($format, strtotime($time . ' + ' . $n . $per));
    $times[$time] = array();
}
```

e: wanted to add, even when I do it like this:

```
$time = date($format, strtotime($time . ' + 1 week'));
```

It won't store the proper value.

Comment: what is $start set to?

Comment: Oh, right, forgot to add. $start is a timestamp that is made from a fetched date from the db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this example can help you;
When I am working with dates, I like the DateTime object, please take a look at the code below (I Hope the comments explain it enough)

```
$times = array(); //array to hold values in

$Start = new DateTime('01-01-2013'); //the start date, may come from db??

$End = new DateTime('01-02-2013'); //the end date (You can also create a new DateTime object and add 90 days if you want)


$Diff = $Start->diff($End); //check how many days are between the two dates, if higher than 90, format by month, else by week

if ($Diff->days > 90) { //from 90 days, show per month instead of weeks
    $per = 'month';
    $format = 'm Y';
} else {
    $per = 'week';
    $format = 'W Y';
}

while($Start < $End) { //loop until $Start equals or is higher than $End

    $times[$Start->format($format)] = 'some data'; //push data into the array 

    $Start->modify('+1 ' . $per); //add X amount of time to the $Start variable 
}


print_r($times);
```

And this code shows:

```
Array
(
    [01 2013] => some data
    [02 2013] => some data
    [03 2013] => some data
    [04 2013] => some data
    [05 2013] => some data
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be good idea to change a logic here and iterate over result items and 'put' them straight away into right periodic groupings so (not tested but i'm sure you'll get the idea):

```
$times = Array();

// apply format for groupings
$format= 'W Y'; 

// traverse results item by item
foreach($results as $item){

    // assumed content of result here - this has to be adapted
    $timestamp = $item['timestamp'];
    $value = $item['value'];
    $key = date($format, $timestamp);

    // new grouping so create new key
    if(!isset($times[$key])) $times[$key] = Array();

    // add item
    $times[$key][] = $value;
}
```

Comment: I agree. The problem's been solved so I'm going to change it into something like this now.

Comment: Wait, I don't think this would work as well as I thought, though. For instance, if a certain month doesn't have any records, the month won't be saved into the array at all, but it should be. So gonna have to save all of them anyway, not just the ones I get from the records, if you catch my drift.

Answer (score 0):

The format accepted to strtotime is string, so you need to convert your $time to string before adding date.

So,

```
 $time               = date($format, strtotime($time->format('Y-m-d')->toString() . ' + ' . $n .' '. 'weeks')); //i think it might be plural "weeks" no "week"
```

Comment: Isn't it parsed as a date string already on the previous line, though?

Comment: yea, i verify here and you don't need ->toString() there. format already return a string.

Answer (score -1):

Read up on this functionality:
[PHP Manual: DateTime:add](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php)